# Javascript Validation - alert message and concatenation issue - form submits after the 5th check no matter what

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, concatenation

Thanks in advanced for any help on this. I am merely a beginner with JS and PHP, and this issue I just can't wrap my head around.

My Problem.. If I remove the last concatenation

```
//fail += validateEmail(form.email.value);
```

the form will bring up the alert, with all appropriate messages and prevent form from submitting. 
When that line is added back in, no matter what the function has in it, it will just automatically go right to the next page without showing any alert, almost like the validation doesn't exist.

Could there be a limit to the number of lines in an alert? I would think it would just truncate if that was the case, not skip the code entirely. I have been pulling my hair out on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code. Its all on one html page called validateTest.html.

(first time posting on this site, and it removes all my html code uggh..

here is just the javascript part:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm(form){
        fail = validateFirstname(form.firstname.value);
        fail += validateLastname(form.lastname.value);
        fail += validateUsername(form.username.value);
        fail += validatePassword(form.password.value);
        fail += validateAge(form.age.value);
        fail += validateEmail(form.email.value);

        if(fail== ""){ return true;
        }else {alert(fail); 
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validateFirstname(field){
        if(field == "") { return "No Firstname was given \n";
        } else return "";
    }

    function validateLastname(field){
        if(field == "") { return "No Lastname was given \n";
        } else  return "";
    }

    function validateUsername(field){
    if (field == "") return "No Username was entered.\n";
    else if (field.length < 5)
        return "Usernames must be at least 5 characters.\n";
    else if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/.test(field))
        return "Only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and _ allowed in Usernames.\n";
    return "";
    }

    function validatePassword(field){
    if (field == "") return "No Password was entered.\n";
    else if (field.length < 6)
        return "Passwords must be at least 6 characters.\n";
    else if (!/[a-z]/.test(field) || ! /[A-Z]/.test(field) ||
       !/[0-9]/.test(field))
        return "Passwords require one each of a-z, A-Z and 0-9.\n";
    return "";
    }

    function validateAge(field){
    if (isNaN(field)) return "No Age was entered.\n";
    else if (field < 18 || field > 110)
        return "Age must be between 18 and 110.\n";
    return "";
    }

    function validateEmail(field){
        if(field == "") { return "Nothing in the slot! \n"; 
        }else 
            return "";
    }



    </script>
```

Can't figure out how to show the html form as when I do it hides the form code from the question. Using the code blocks simply only shows one line from the html.. annoying.

so here is the form post line (removed "<>" to actually display it):
     form method="post" name="myform" action="adduser.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);"

Each form line Is done similar to this: 
 input type="text" maxlength="64" name="email">

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle reproducing this problem?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110126/how-can-i-paste-html-markup-into-a-stack-overflow-question-field) may help you write HTML markup in #SO

Comment: Use curly braces, your code can quickly get out of whack if you rely on JS to correctly interpret your line breaks.

Comment: I could not reproduce this problem with the given javascript (with dummy values), i would assume that there is a problem with your form values.